# Swagger - how to remove XML as a formatting option; only want JSON formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I am building a WEB API project and it seems like I am unable to remove the default of Swagger defaulting to XML formatting.  I tried removing the AddXmlSerializerFormatters method call but my controller responses fail at that point.  Anyone have a simple way to eliminate all XML in Web API and Swagger and only support JSON?  Below is my current code in Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    options.InputFormatters.RemoveType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter>();
                    options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter>();
                }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;

            });
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("/companies")]
        [ValidateModelState]
        [SwaggerOperation("GetCompanies")]
        public virtual IActionResult GetCompanies()
        {
            ICompanyRepository _companyRespository = new CompaniesRepository();
            List<Company> companies = _companyRespository.GetAll();
            return Ok(companies);
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you got the `[Produces("application/json")]` attribute on your controller classes?

From [Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/aspnet/aspnetcore.docs/getstarted-swashbuckle-aspnetcore/?tabs=visual-studio):

> Mark the model with attributes, found in the
> System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace, to help drive the
> Swagger UI components.
>
> Add the [Produces("application/json")] attribute to the API
> controller. Its purpose is to declare that the controller's actions
> support a response content type of application/json.
>
> The Response Content Type drop-down selects this content type as the
> default.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have done that prior and it does not work?

Comment: Can you post the code of a controller and action?

Comment: Yes and I should have thanked you for responding and for helping.

Comment: See above, let me know if you need more. Thanks.

Comment: Ok no problem. For me (using Swashbuckle to generate Swagger docs and UI), using this attribute removes the xml formatting option, e.g:
[Produces("application/json")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase

Comment: this doesn't work with .net core, you should generate an OperationFilter and programmatically do it there